# VSCode settings.json error - incorrect type expected string

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

how do i fix the error shown in the pic, i was trying to edit my VSCode settings.json, installed the extension Ruff and tried to edit the settings based on an article I've read here:

https://medium.com/@ordinaryindustries/the-ultimate-vs-code-setup-for-python-538026b34d94

but i get the error shown in the pic below

[image]

Comment: if you remove the text `true` and ask what intellisence suggests, are these really the lines causing the error? Remove them to see if something else is the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart Tips(`Ctrl+Space`) displays these two settings with five values, which are：

[image]

**"always":** Triggers Code Actions on explicit saves and auto saves triggered by window or focus changes.

**"explicit":** Triggers Code Actions only when explicitly saved

**"never":** Never triggers Code Actions on save

**"false":** Never triggers Code Actions on save. This value will be deprecated in favor of "never".

**"true":** Triggers Code Actions only when explicitly saved. This value will be deprecated in favor of "explicit".

From the explanation, it is clear that `false` and `true` are about to be deprecated, so please use the corresponding `"never"` or `"explicit"`.

Comment: i restarted vscode before when i had the error thinking it needed it but still had the error, closed it used pycharm for few hours then opened vscode again and somehow it replaced the values `true` with the values `explicit`, no error now it fixed itself